# Math methods inside classes in Python

Tags: python, function, class, math, methods

I'm very new to classes in Python. Was trying to implement a very simple one that is for an exponential function y = a * exp(-b*x).
Here is my code:

```
class DR(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def value(self,x):
        return self.a * exp(-self.b * x)
```

When i instantiate this class with:

```
f = DR(1.0, 0.1)
```

followed by

```
f.value(1)
```

I get a Nameerror: global name 'exp' is not defined. I realise that I probably need to import math or numpy modules, but not sure where/how in the class.

Comment: If any of the answers solved the problem, is good that you mark it as _accepted_ (big checkbox to the left of the answer). It'll give you reputation points, it'll give the person that spent time answering points and most importantly, it'll help future readers see that the answer was helpful. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't import them *in* the class, you import the necessary libraries at the top of your file:

```
from math import exp

class DR(object):
    ...
```

You should read the [PEP8 document](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).